# service connection created using az cli not working

Tags: azure, automation, azure-devops, azure-cli

I want to automate service connection creation for a given azure devops project as a part of my deploy script. I looked into Terraform but it does not support it yet. ARM template also does not have anything for service connection.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/service_endpoint?view=azure-devops

This link has some notes on how to do it. I have captured the post request body as the link says, and stored it in **config.json** file

I am running the following command to create a service principle.

```
az devops service-endpoint create --service-endpoint-configuration config.json --organization "https://dev.azure.com/ojaskale" --project "Test Project"
```

This does create a service connection but this one does not work. If I create a service principle from console It works as expected.

I am getting following error message.

> The pipeline is not valid. Job Build: Step Docker input
>   containerRegistry references service connection
>   **acrserviceconnectiontest** which could not be found. The service
>   connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For
>   authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.

I can see **acrserviceconnectiontest** in my build.yml.

Azure guidelines say I need to copy the post requests body and fill in the required details. post body does not have **servicePrincipalId** by default. I did some research and figured out I need to create one and assign roles to it which I am doing. There are two scripts given here, I am following those.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal

Once I create service principle I get following output.

> Service principal ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   Service principal password: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I have tried both of them in place of **servicePrincipalId** but none of them seem to work.

service principle id of the working service connection is different than one I create using cli.

I think I am very close to getting it working, as I can see service connection getting created but it does not work. Can someone point me what I am missing or doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for the service connection which you are referencing you should use whatever is under the `name` property in your config.json

Comment: I have it set up that way.

Comment: well, easy way to test it, go to project settings and look at service connections. it would have a different name there

Comment: I am very certain, service connection name in project setting (coming from config.json) matches the one in build.yml.